# How to speed up map building with gmapping?

Tags: ros

I have a pipeline that tries different parameters of gmapping and save the results to a folder. After letting them run I can just examine the pictures and see which maps turned out well and chose those parameters in the future. Now my rosbag that I play is 6 minutes longs, so every run takes 6 minutes with the amount of parameters there are in gmapping it would take days to test even the most important ones. Now I know I can replay the rosbags at a faster rate, but when I do that gmapping creates very strange looking maps and they are all distorted. I am using "rosparam set use_sim_time True" before running my bag and gmapping. Not sure if this prevents gmapping of getting the speed up bags correctly. Is there some way to increase the speed at which gmapping can create a map from a rosbag that is being played faster?

Small side question: What would be the most important parameters probably for a differential drive robot to test for. Right now I test minimumScore, resampleThreshold, particles. Are the other important ones, or a guideline how to tune these parameters?

Comment: Are you playing the `rosbag` using the `--clock` option?

Comment: No, would this be helpfull?

Comment: It sounds like you might have issues with timing of the messages to gmapping, so I would guess it is worth a shot trying to publish the clock also.

Comment: Ok I will try that. So publish clock and play at a faster rate?

Comment: Yes! BTW, you still need to also set `use_sim_time` to true.

Comment: It did not work.